# how to pass variable in the url from gridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, gridview, parameter-passing

I have Gridview of the form results. I am trying to add an url to one of the field. How do I pass the variable in the url. intLib is the variable. This is what I have:

VB.Net Code:

```
<a href="EditIncident.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("Inci_ID")%>&Val2="& intLib>
     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Inci_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a session variable and passed it on to the next page.

Thanks for your help.